# ES6 Proxies - Is it possible to capture methods called upon a null object before they happen?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, proxy-pattern

I'm working with an API that returns a schema for validating a form before users can submit their data.

For example, the schema has a `User` class featuring an attribute  called `email`.  If there is an error, `User.validators.getEmailErrors()` returns an `Array` of all the errors, e.g. `['Email address cannot be blank', 'Email addresses must match']`.

*However*, if the field is valid, and no errors are found, `getEmailErrors()` returns `null`.

In my app, I want to safely chain more methods from `getEmailErrors()`, e.g. `getEmailErrors().join(',')`, but without checking for `null` beforehand.  Rather, is there a way, e.g. using ES6 proxies, to make `getEmailAddress()` aware of whether it will return an `Array`, and to safely ignore any methods like `join()` in case it returns `null`?

The easy solution would be to return an empty `Array` in the valid case instead of `null`, but assume I can't change that.

Comment: Why not `(getEmailErrors() || []).join(',')`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It can be done, indirectly.

Following code was originated from [HERE](https://medium.com/@DjamelH/es6-proxy-b2416cf67f7b), and I add some code for testing.

Thanks for the original author, Djamel Hassaine.

```js
{
    class test {
  constructor () {
   this.in = 0;
        }
        sum ( a, b ) {
            this.in += a + b;
   return this;
        }
    }
    let k = new test();

    function traceMethodCalls(obj) {
        const handler = {
            get(target, propKey, receiver) {
                console.log( target, propKey, receiver );
    console.log( this );
    console.log( handler === this );
    const targetValue = Reflect.get(target, propKey, receiver);
                if (typeof targetValue === 'function') {
                    return function (...args) {
                        console.log('CALL', propKey, args);
      console.log( this );
      console.log( this === receiver );
                        return targetValue.apply(this, args); // (A)
                    }
                } else {
                    return targetValue;
                }
            }
        };
        return new Proxy(obj, handler);    
    }

 let l = traceMethodCalls( k );
 console.log( l.sum( 1, 2 ) );
 console.log( l );
 console.log( l.sum( 1, 2 ) );
 console.log( l );
}
```

Another way:

```js
User.validators.getEmailErrorsOriginal = User.validators.getEmailErrors
User.validators.getEmailErrors = function ( ...args ) {
  return ( this.getEmailErrorsOriginal( ...args ) || [] );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
(getEmailErrors() || []).join(',')
```

Is this what you look for ? Its not very clean but it certainly short ...